# LIKE clause not returning the values as expected

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

What I want to next is to filter the dropdown box based on any value typed in. eg. If a word is say `"16 cat123"` usually the user would have to start off with typing the number `"16"` or the number `"1"` for it to show the results. Instead of this I would want if the user should start off by typing `"cat123"` then it still bring up the `"16 cat123"` which is the original item. How can I achieve this?I know it is a combination of the `LIKE` clause with my `SELECT` but currently it is still operating the same way, which is only sending back the values by the first letter entered. Here is my current query:

```
  string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Carimed WHERE Item_Description LIKE '%" + comboBox3.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%'; ";
```

What am I missing?

Updated with full function:

```
private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            string connectionString = "Data Source=CMDLAP126;Initial Catalog=Carimed_Inventory;User ID = sa; Password = 123456;";
            string query = " "SELECT * FROM dbo.Carimed WHERE Item_Description LIKE '%" + comboBox3.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%' ";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string cari_code = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("item#"));
                textBox2.Text = cari_code;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your logic appears to be correct here, `LIKE '%value%'` is the correct syntax for doing "contains" search, you may want to put together a more complete example to show the problem.

Comment: Parametrize your query as well or a clever input (SQL injection) could destroy your db.

Comment: I found a work around by using the guide of this user from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/631196/combobox-with-suggest-ability-based-on-substring-s)
What was done by the author was that of overriding the default combobox setting in winforms. I just found a way to tie it into my code and got it up and running. Hopefully this is of help to someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Carimed WHERE Item_Description LIKE '" + comboBox3.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%'; ";
```

Answer (score 0):

```c#
string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Carimed WHERE Item_Description LIKE '%" + comboBox3.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%' ";
```

Maybe remove the semicolon that is part of your query string?

Comment: That was something I tried while debugging.  Same issue.  Thanks for the suggestion all the same

Comment: Everything looks correct.  Check the value from comboBox2.Text is  what you are expecting with no extra characters.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the extra `;` in the query, it looks correct. If applicable in your application, you might want to trim the the content ( `comboBox3.Text.Trim()` )so that `"cat123 "` would match `"16 cat123"`. And as suggested in the comments, you should parameterize your query.

Comment: Trimmed it already from the database side so no problems there, and yeah am aware that it should be parameraterized,  just for practice for the time being

Comment: Do you mean the data in the database is trimmed? Or the user input is trimmed? For instance, if I type "cat123      " would your query ultimately execute SELECT ... FROM .. WHERE Item_Description LIKE '%cat123%' ?

Comment: Yes but in case I didn't I tried what you suggested, still no luck

Comment: Can you show a bit more code? Maybe the whole piece where the query is constructed, executed, and the result set fetched?

Comment: Well, there are a few things that might be improved. But maybe your issue is the line `textBox2.Text = cari_code;`. The content of the text box is replaced in every iteration of the loop, which means it will only show the last item in the result set.

Comment: But that's just outputting to a textBox, I don't see how it affects it that much

Comment: I assume when you mentioned some results were not returned, you were looking at the actual result set and not to the output displayed by you application?

Comment: Yes that's what am referring to. Keep in mind based on the value selected from comboBox3, that the corresponding value from the database loads into textBox2

Comment: Other than trimming the content of the user input ( comething like `comboBox3.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''")` ) and not replacing the content of the text box ( something like `textBox2.Text += (cari_code; + " ") ` or whatever delimiter you want) I don't see anything that would prevent from showing the expected results. You might want to run the query directly into the database, maybe there extra invisible characters in the data.

Comment: it actually works in the database so am guessing it's an oversight in my code

Comment: Try making the adjustments I mention on my previous comment to see if that helps

Comment: Unfortunately it's the same problem even after trying your suggestions

Comment: One thing I overlooked, it seems the handler is for the `SelectedIndexChanged` event. This event will be raised until you select something from the list, not as you type. Therefore, if you type _cat123_, your method won't execute unless _cat123_ is in the list and you select it.

Comment: But it's a autocomplete so even if they type, the value from the list still comes up and is selected. Therefore it still operates the same way